# exporting mysql query column headings

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

I have the following query...

```
    public function get_invoice_user_summary_csv($invoice_table_id)
    {
    $sql_get_user_summ = "
                            SELECT `billingHistory`.`$invoice_table_id`.userId as userId, ipCore.users.firstname, ipCore.users.surname, COUNT(`billingHistory`.`$invoice_table_id`.id) AS totalNum, SUM(`billingHistory`.`$invoice_table_id`.durationSeconds) AS totalDuration, (SUM(`billingHistory`.`$invoice_table_id`.priceMin)+SUM(`billingHistory`.`$invoice_table_id`.priceCon)) AS totalCost
                            FROM `billingHistory`.`$invoice_table_id`
                            LEFT JOIN ipCore.users ON `billingHistory`.`$invoice_table_id`.userId = ipCore.users.id
                            GROUP BY userId
                            ORDER BY ipCore.users.surname ASC, ipCore.users.firstname ASC;";

    $query = $this->db_mtvm->query($sql_get_user_summ);
    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
            {
            $line = '';
            $value = '';
            foreach($row as $value)
                {
                if((!isset($value)) || ($value == ""))
                    {
                    $value = ",";
                    }
                else
                    {
                    $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
                    $value = '"' . $value . '"' . ",";
                    }
                $line .= $value;
                }
            print substr(str_replace("\r", "", trim($line)), 0, -1)."\r\n";
            flush();
            ob_flush();
            }
        }
    else return false;
    }
```

this return formatted array for csv out put in a different controller.

however it is just the body of data (as i expected). However I have read a few questions with i think similar things, but canot quite work out in this example where I need to put the column headings. either manually entered, or I will assign these from the sql query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You now loop through the results, by doing this:

```
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
```

You should change your script so that on the first iteration of this loop, you fetch the column headers and output them. A quick way to do this would be to change the line I quoted above to:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
    if($i === 0)
        echo implode(",", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
    $i++;
    [...]
```

I notice you're creating the CSV string yourself. An easier way to do that is by using [`fputcsv()`](http://www.php.net/fputcsv). By default it writes to a file handle, but you can also buffer the output in memory and fetch the result as a string, [like this example shows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php#74118).

Comment: ok was not really aware of fputcsv. I have just seen example and assume it works exactly the same on mutlidimensional arrays?. Thanks!